# Statistical tool to test relationship between variables and perceptions with Likert-Scale

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance

I am currently doing my research about perceptions of residents toward community development. I am trying to find out if there's a relationship between the respondents' profile or their socioeconomic characteristics and their perceptions toward development. I used Likert-scale to measure their perceptions toward and the indicators for development. What statistical tool should I use? Is chi-square and T-test right? Or correlations like Pearson and Spearman's the better one?

Answer (score 1):

You could use, for example, [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression), with respondent characteristics as predictors and likert-scale perceptions as a response.